# Vim option scoping: global-local, local, and global

Tags: vim

The Vim help documentation on `|options|` makes distinctions between options and option values; and between global, local, and global-local options. It is extremely confusing, especially given `|local-options|`:

"It's possible to set a local window option specifically for a type of buffer.... Vim keeps a global value of the
local window options, which is used when editing another buffer.  Each window has its own copy of these values.  Thus these are local to the window, but
global to all buffers in the window."

In the subsequent example, it shows that `:setlocal list` makes the local window option local to a buffer. But what about global or global-local window options?

Can anyone explain the reason for the difference in terminology between options and values, and between the three types of options?

Comment: I think some options are possibly buffer-local while others are window-local? Needs more investigating. PS check out [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's pretty easy, IMO. Just think of what an option is used for.

Say, `confirm` is global, as it makes sense per Vim instance. Hence, even if you execute `setlocal confirm`, that would silently change a global option, as it's the only one existing.

Next, `expandtab` is local per buffer (note: some options can be local per window, such as `:h 'diff'`, for instance). However, there exists both global `expandtab` (which is essentially is "the current default value" of `expandtab` for newly created buffers) and local `expandtab` (one per each existing buffer). Also note that some "defaults" are pretty much useless (e.g. `filetype` will be set by `ftdetect` anyway, but, nonetheless, the global `filetype` exists).

Now, what's a global-local thing? That's simply an option which may (or may not) be created for every existing buffer. But, of course, there's always a global option of this kind.

How it's different from an ordinary local option? Say you have in your vimrc:

```
setglobal noexpandtab noautoread
```

Now you run your Vim and enter:

```
:setlocal expandtab? autoread?
```

And then you get in response:

```
noexpandtab
--autoread
```

That means you have a *buffer-local copy* of your global `expandtab`, but local `autoread` was not created at all in the current buffer, so Vim would use a global value whatever it'd be.

To summarize said above:

1. "Global option" means that no local value exists at all. So global value is always used.
2. "Local option" means that all buffers (or windows) always have a copy of their own, and so "global" value is only meaningful as the default value.
3. "Global-local option" means that some buffers (or windows) may have their copy, but others may not. So Vim uses the current local option if set, otherwise it uses the global option.

Comment: I see! Global options have no local value, local options always have a local value, and global-local options may have a local value (that can be removed via `set {option}<`). That is simple. 
To connect this to my earlier quote, though, it seems like a local window option has a global value that is the default for all of a given window's buffers, and `setlocal` sets a value for that specific window-buffer combination?

Comment: @LumpyGrads Concerning this topic, Vim's behaviour is described in detail under `:h local-options`

Comment: Not sure it’s helpful to tell someone struggling to understand that it’s easy.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble My bad. That reminds me an old joke: a professor says "These students are so stupid! I had to repeat the proof for them three times in a row. Now even I've understood it, but they still don't".

Comment: @Matt |local-options| was in fact the source of my confusion. It's helpful to have another human explain it in a new way. I think I understand for the most part now, so thank you!

Comment: `Well, it's pretty easy, IMO.` Only superficially.
@LumpyGrads Yes, you can use a mental model where the value of a window-local option is tied to a couple buffer/window.  But it will break down in many circumstances.  There are several parameters which can influence how a window-local option is set; like whether your Vim binary includes the patches 8.0.1836 and 7.4.2212, whether you started Vim with `-o`, `-O`, `-p`, or whether you've sourced a session file.

Comment: @LumpyGrads And there are exceptions; some window-local options are really tied to a window (not a couple buffer/window).  Then, you have to consider whether the buffer has already been displayed in another window in the past, and whether that window has been closed (see here https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/11525#issuecomment-580680557).  I'm sure I'm forgetting several other parameters.  Then, there are bugs.

Comment: As a former short-term Emacs user, any generally accurate mental model of (Neo)vim is useful. I can handle the corner cases once I grasp the basics. It's good to know some of the corner cases for further investigation.